# Get a path between graph nodes using breadth-first search

Tags: python, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel, graph, breadth-first-search

This code is meant to implement a `Graph` class which has a method that returns a path between 2 nodes using breadth-first search.

I'm doing this to improve my style and to improve my knowledge of fundamental algorithms/data structures for an upcoming coding interview.

```
from queue import PriorityQueue
from collections import deque
from copy import deepcopy


class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes = dict()

    def add_node(self, id):
        new_node = Node(id)
        self.nodes[id] = new_node
        return new_node

    def get_node(self, id):
        node = self.nodes[id] if id in self.nodes else None
        return node

    def bfs(self, start, end):
        queue = PriorityQueue()
        queue.put((0, start))
        seen = set([start])
        parents = dict()

        while not queue.empty():
            cur_node = queue.get(0)[1]
            if cur_node is not end:
                for neighbour in cur_node.neighbours:
                    if neighbour not in seen:
                        dist_to_neighbour = cur_node.neighbours[neighbour]
                        queue.put((dist_to_neighbour, neighbour))
                        parents[neighbour] = cur_node
                        seen.add(neighbour)
            else:
                path = self.get_path(start, end, parents)
                return path
        return None

    def get_path(self, start, end, parents):
        path = deque([end])
        cur_node = end
        while cur_node is not start:
            cur_node = parents[cur_node]
            path.appendleft(cur_node)
        return list(path)


class Node:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.neighbours = dict()

    def add_neighbour(self, to, weight):
        self.neighbours[to] = weight
```

I have a few ideas about what might be improved but I'm not sure how to do it (or even if it's worth doing).

1. There might be a better way to do `get_node()` instead of squashing it into 2 lines like how I've done it.
2. Maybe `cur_node = queue.get(0)[1]` should be 2 lines?
3. Change `dist_to_neighbour = cur_node.neighbours[neighbour]` to use a method instead of using dictionary notation (which might be a little awkward). Maybe I should have a method instead?
4. Using something else instead of a `deque` in `get_path()` (especially in an interview context where deque might be a bit too exotic).
5. Have more comments?

[Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/147388/return-path-between-graph-nodes-using-breadth-first-search) is my previous attempt at this code. I've also used the answers to my depth-first search attempts [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/147558/return-a-path-between-graph-nodes-using-depth-first-search-redo) and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/147543/return-path-between-graph-nodes-using-depth-first-search) to write this code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see that you are using `add_node` or `get_node` anywhere, but I'm assuming you would when actually using this class.

Nevertheless, I think these functions would better be called `__setitem__` and `__getitem__`, allowing usage, such as `g = Graph(); g[5] = Node(5)` and `print g[5]`. This would also make initializing the graph easier, which leads me to my next recommendation.

I would expect the `Graph` class to take an argument on initialization to directly build a graph (without having to manually add every single node).

Lastly, `get_node` can be greatly simplified by using `dict.get`, which returns `None` when the key is not present in the dictionary.

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, nodes=None):
        self.nodes = dict()
        if nodes is not None:
            for _id in nodes:
                self[_id] = Node(_id)

    def __setitem__(self, _id, val):
        self.nodes[_id] = val

    def __getitem__(self, _id):
        return self.nodes.get(_id)

    def add_node(self, _id):
        self[_id] = Node(_id)

    ...
```

This allows initializing an instance like this: `Graph([1,2,3])`. It does not, however, allow initializing a nested structure.

Regarding your questions:

1. Use `dict.get`
2. I would maybe use `_, cur_node = queue.get(0)` to make it clearer that you don't need the priority here.
3. I think it is still quite readable.
4. `deque` does not seem too exotic to me, but then again, I don't perform job interviews, so who know.

Last but not least, I would have a look at whether you really need `queue.PriorityQueue` here. One of its features is that it is thread-safe, because it performs locking when adding or popping values from the queue. However, it also incurs a performance hit because of this (I saw a factor 2 being discussed for Python 2.6).

Instead you could roll your own implementation using `heapq`, similar to the one shown in [the implementation details for `heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/_sources/library/heapq.txt), maybe without the part about `REMOVED` entries, because you don't change the priority of a `neighbour` once you have calculated it. So you could use:

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop
import itertools

class PriorityQueue:
    def __init__(self, tasks=None):
        '''A new PriorityQueue.
        Parameters:
            tasks:    iterable of (priority, task) tuples'''
        self.pq = []                         # list of entries arranged in a heap
        self.counter = itertools.count()     # unique sequence count

        if tasks is not None:
            for priority, task in tasks:
                self.add_task(task, priority)

    def add_task(self, task, priority=0):
        'Add a new task'
        count = next(self.counter)
        entry = (priority, count, task)
        heappush(self.pq, entry)

    def pop_task(self):
        'Remove and return the lowest priority task. Raise KeyError if empty.'
        if self.pq:
            _, _, task = heappop(self.pq)
            return task
        raise KeyError('pop from an empty priority queue')
```

This should basically be how `queue.PriorityQueue` is implemented as well, but without the locking. Note that `heapq` is implemented in C, so it is quite fast. You would have to make some performance comparisons to see how this performs with respect to `queue.PriorityQueue`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using `__setitem__` and `__getitem__` definitely make it nicer. Being able to initialise a graph with a list makes sense. Your answers to my thoughts were quite helpful. Also, your section about using heapq due to performance was very interesting. I learned a lot of new interesting stuff from that. Thanks :)